# Zend Framework - Active Record + Form Generation + Validation?

Tags: zend-framework, orm, activerecord

I'd like to use an Active Record design pattern in a few of my projects and I'd like to have the models, validation and form generation set up for me. Symfony is really nice for this, as is the framework I use in my day job.

Is Zend Framework able to do this for me, or do I have a lot of legwork to do myself to get ZF tied in with and ORM like Doctrine, then tie that in with form generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to my knowledge you cant do this with just Zend Framework.
[Here](http://ruben.savanne.be/articles/integrating-zend-framework-and-doctrine) is an article on integrating Doctrine and Zend

Comment: Great thanks - an updated version of that post can be found here: http://www.danceric.net/2009/06/06/doctrine-orm-and-zend-framework/

I was hoping I wouldn't have so much legwork in getting a modular active record app built with ZF but it seems ZF leaves you on your own somewhat in regards to pulling their various components together.

http://www.danceric.net/2009/06/06/doctrine-orm-and-zend-framework/